# Red5: Create server side thumbnails of video streams?

Tags: java, video-streaming, thumbnails, red5

I have a flex video streaming application using a Red5 streaming server.
Now I need to generate thumbnails of the streams every X seconds to display them on a web page. I know, that it is possible to create client side thumbnails via the flex application which generates the stream, but is it also possible to create the thumbnails on server side?

Answer (score 0):

Try [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) , it can generate video thumbnails on server side.